# ruby how to keep decimals inside of a hash value with gets.to_i

Tags: arrays, ruby, integer, gets, ruby-hash

I have

```
price_input = gets.strip.to_i
```

and I am trying to add it to an array of hashes. The adding to array works, but the .gets.strip.to_i removes any decimals. Is there a way to add it without it removing the decimals?

for further understanding, I have an existing array of hashes where ( price: [an integer] ) and I am adding these integers together with code later, so I need the .to_i because I can't add strings and integers

Comment: To handle monetary values, you could store them as cents, use `BigDecimal` or the [RubyMoney](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem.

Comment: `gets.to_f` will work, but handling money as a Float is generally a bad idea..

Answer (score 1):

### Storing Input Strings in BigDecimal

Integers are not Floats, and Floats are a bad way to handle financial representations. There are gems for handling money that abstract away the various issues with floating point math, but if you're just looking for something simple:

```rb
require "bigdecimal"

print "Enter a price: "
price_input = BigDecimal(gets)
puts "You entered $#{price_input.to_f.round 2}"
```

You don't even have to chomp or strip your input, as [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) will handle that for you. However, please keep in mind that even though BigDecimal or Real will correctly handle fractional cents, anything involving fractions of a penny can lead to rounding errors of one sort or another when you convert back to a Float with a precision of 2, so you'll need to decide what to do about rounding regardless of your internal representation.

### See Also

1. [Float#floor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Float.html#method-i-floor)
2. [Float#ceil](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Float.html#method-i-ceil)
3. [Float#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Float.html#method-i-round)
4. [Float#rationalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Float.html#method-i-rationalize)

Comment: _"when you convert back to a Float"_ – just don't :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_f` method. It converts `String` object to `Float` object. You also don't need `strip` method

```
"  0.2  ".to_f
# => 0.2
```

or in your case

```
price_input = gets.to_f
```

Keep in mind that when two integers interact, the result will always be an integer. If one number is an integer and the second is a float, the result will be a float

Comment: Beware, though : `"not_a_float".to_f #=> 0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, this way if someone enters characters instead of a number, an error will be raised.

```
price_input = Float(gets)
```